# How to pass a permission via Django Rest API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I would like to create a custom permission that return true / flase depending on whether the user is the author of a story or not and pass this information via the restAPI. So when the author is requesting a story where he is not author the permission returns "false" and i can access these information `IsStoryOwner: "False"`via my API. Something like this should be the result:

```
 "user": {
        "id": 35,
        "username": "HII",
        "user_permissions": [

         IsStoryOwner: "False",

        ]
    }
```

However i struggle to implement that. I wrote the following permission:

```
class IsStoryOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Check if authenticated user is  story author
    """
    def has_object_permission(self,request,obj,**kwargs):
        if request.user.id == story.author:
            return True
        return False
```

Than i integrated the permission in my UserAPI

```
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
  permission_classes = [
    permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsStoryOwner
  ]
  serializer_class = UserSerializer

  def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user
```

However the permission is not appearing in my API and the `"user_permissions": []` remains empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SerializerMethodField. Don't forget this, Django send 403 status code to client when your IsStoryOwner return False.

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user_permissions = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('user_permissions', 'other_fields')
        model = YourUserModel

    def get_user_permissions(self, obj):
         request = self.context['request'] #
         return request.user.id == obj.story.author
```